# Generate permutations of characters in arrays - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I'm working on a JavaScript function that will generate permutations of a nested array (let's call it input). I want to do it in a way, that the length of permutations will be of *input.length*.
So, given

```
var input = [["0", "5", "9"], ["2", "3"], ["0", "5", "4"]];
```

I'm looking to generate permutations of length 3, containing any of ["0", "5", "9"] as a first character, any of ["2", "3"] as the second character etc.

My main challenge is I don't understand recursion well enough to apply it to the problem at hand. I understand the general principle and can step through a given function in order to understand how it behaves (obviously, the more complex the function is, the longer it takes me to understand it. When I can't wrap my mind around a function, I use sticky notes and map each call using a separate note on my wall. This way I can easier visualize the pattern and usually after stepping through a couple of calls my understanding becomes much better). 
However, if I were to write the same function that I'm able to understand that way, I would probably struggle.

So I've found a function that generates permutation of a simple string with an intention to modify it in a way so that it handles a nested array and generates desired output.

```
var permutations = [];
function doPerm(str, arr) {
    if (typeof (str) == 'string') str = str.split('');
    if (str.length == 0) permutations.push(arr.join(''));
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        var x = str.splice(i, 1);
        arr.push(x);
        doPerm(str, arr);
        arr.pop();
        str.splice(i, 0, x);
    }
}
```

A modification would add another level on top of the existing function (as from what I imagine "rest" variable would have to be a permutation itself).

However, I'm sure there's a way to simplify the problem. 
Any guidance or possible solutions to this will be appreciated.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? An example of before and after would be nice.

Comment: If I understood your question correctly, given `input = [["3, "4"], ["8", "9"], ["5", "6"]];` I want the function to generate 
`output = ["385", "386", "395", "396", "485", "486", "495", "496"];`
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a recursive solution in JavaScript. I tried to match your words with the appropriate step in the function, see the comments.

```js
function f(input, index, result) {

      // "...the length of permutations will be of input.length"

      if (index == input.length) {
        $("#output").append(JSON.stringify(result) + "<br>"); // output
        return; // terminate this particular thread
      }

      // "containing any of ["0", "5", "9"] as a first character"

      for (var i = 0; i < input[index].length; i++) {

        var copyOfResult = result.slice();
        copyOfResult.push(input[index][i]);

        // "any of ["2", "3"] as the second character etc."

        f(input, index + 1, copyOfResult);

      }
    }

     // start the recursion;

    f([["0", "5", "9"],["2", "3"],["0", "5", "4"]], 0, []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try the naive way,

```
foreach input1 in input[1]
    foreach input2 in input[2]
        foreach input3 in input[3]
            print input1*100 + input2*10 + input3*1
```

It should be easy to implement and alternate the above code segment to get what you want :)

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the OP wants this to work for different lengths of input, so a fixed number of nested loops won't work.